# How to make port forwarding in initramfs stage?

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, reverse-tunnel, initramfs-tools

I can install dropbear into the initramfs and successfully connect to this ssh server (IP: `my_initramfs_ip`) on boot stage, as described [here](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/53fd10092b5e82ed1dba5d3011ac54c6).

Now I want to perform a port forwarding as a client at the same stage. For this purpose, I installed dropbear ssh client (`dbclient`) into the initramfs and in order to check if it works correctly, I tried to connect to one of my servers within the initramfs:

```
initramfs# dbclient user@myserver
user@myserver password: ...
```

Which works perfectly and I can log in to `myserver`. Now I want to perform a port forwarding, just like I usually do when the actual system boots up:

```
initramfs# dbclient -R 1234:localhost:22 myserver_ip
```

But the port forward simply doesn't work when I try to connect by:

```
myserver$ ssh root@localhost -p 1234
```

with the error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

So, how can I make the port forwarding on boot stage?

## Edit:

I tried to add the library files that `dbclient` opens while performing a successful reverse port forwarding into the initramfs just in case:

```
myserver$ strace dbclient -R 7000:localhost:22 user@1.1.1.1 2>&1 | grep open | grep lib | sed 's/open("//' | sed 's/",.*//'
user@1.1.1.1's password: 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
```

...but there is no success.

Comment: Rationale: When I install my OS on a LUKS partition (target machine), I need to unlock the disk over network, via SSH, as [described here](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/53fd10092b5e82ed1dba5d3011ac54c6). The problem is that the SSH connection requires a port forwarding in the remote firewall so that I can connect my target machine. I want to make my target connect and put its SSHD port onto a server so that I could connect my target over my server. This will eliminate the port forwarding requirement.

Comment: I tried to simplify the question by removing the additional `nc` experiment part so it's now simply a port forwarding question.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. The tricky part is that `... -R 1234:localhost:22` still doesn't work even you make the `lo` interface up but `... -R 1234:127.0.0.1:22` works when `lo` is up. Would you consider copying your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loopback interface may be down at `initramfs` host. Maybe all you need is

```
ifconfig lo up
```

(Inspired by [this answer on Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375462/108618)).